# How does thrust set_intersection works?

Tags: c++, algorithm, intersection, thrust, set-intersection

I'm trying to figure out how `thrust::set_intersection` works but from my test results I get even more confused on what this function is doing.

Here is a few examples:

```
const int size1 = 5;
const int size2 = 5;
int A1[size1] = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int A2[size2] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int *result = new int[1000];
int *result_end = thrust::set_intersection(A1, A1 + size1, A2, A2 + size2, result, thrust::less<int>());
```

returns `2, 3, 4, 5`

```
thrust::equal_to<int>()
```

returns `2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

```
thrust::greater<int>()
```

returns nothing

I do understand what the default `set_intersection` does and I agree with the result, but for any other example I'm totally lost where the result came from? Or how it was calculated?

Is it known how this algorithm works? Can someone explain it?

**EDIT:**

My goal is given 2 sets of tuples(lets say of size 2):

```
A={(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)}
B={(0, 2), (2, 2), (3, 3)}
```

So I want to define on operator on tuples like >< that returns all the element that satisfy the operator:

`><` defined like `a.first > b.first && a.second < b.second`

so the answer is only A[0] and B[0].

So you can't achieve this with `set_intersection` right?

**EDIT answer:**
Never mind I found the answer [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) by these rules such operator won't be 'Strict Weak Ordering' operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To two input sets need to be sorted according to the last argument, the comparator.

- In the first example they are, and the function works correctly.
- The sets are not sorted according to `thrust::greater<int>()`. Since the prerequisites are not met, the function cannot do its job.
- `thrust::equal_to<int>()` is not even a valid comparator.

Comment: So is this possible to create my own comparator? For example >< on tuples, this operator is true when a.first > b.first && a.second < b.second. If I understand correctly, you can't. Right?

Comment: The operator is true if `a.first < b.first || (a.first == b.first && a.second < b.second)`.